# Parsing output from ping

Tags: python, parsing, ping

Having trouble trying to parse data from pinging an IP address. I've been trying to parse data from the ping results and format it like:

```
IP, TimeToPing (ms)
10.1.2.3, 10
```

This is where the script is at so far:

```
import sys
import ipaddress
import subprocess
import os
import re
#Main routine

def main():
    address = sys.argv[1]
    pingthis = ['ping', '-c', '1', address]
    header = "IP, TimeToPing (ms)"
    subprocess.call(pingthis)
    re.search(r'.* time=(.*) ms', os.system('ping -c1'))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Is your question how you can split a string at a delimiter (e.g, `', '` in this case)? Or how to access the output of a subprocess?

Comment: Access the output of ping

Comment: You mean you are asking this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4760215/running-shell-command-and-capturing-the-output

Comment: gave subprocess.check_output(['ping']) and got a AttributeError: module 'subprocess' has no attribute 'check_ouput'

Comment: There is a pingparsing module in pypi (https://pypi.org/project/pingparsing/) that will probably do what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```py
import re
import subprocess
import sys

from tabulate import tabulate


def main():
    address = sys.argv[1]
    pingthis = ['ping', '-c', '1', address]
    r = (
        subprocess
        .run(
            pingthis,
            stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
            check=True,
        )
        .stdout
        .decode('utf-8')
    )
    table = tabulate(
        [[address, (re.search(r'time=(\d+)', r).group(1))]],
        headers=["IP", "TimeToPing (ms)"],
        tablefmt="simple",
    )
    print(table)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Output for `python main.py 8.8.8.8`

```
IP         TimeToPing (ms)
-------  -----------------
8.8.8.8                 14
```

Comment: Thank you for the help and your time. I will need to check out tabulate and stdoutput=subprocess.PIPE and read up on that.